# Could someone share AF calibration settings for Sigma 18-35mm lens on Nikon D3300?

Tags: autofocus, sigma, nikon-d3300

I have auto focus problems with Sigma 18-35 which I recently bought on D3300. I would like to see other's AF adjustment/calibration settings. I am having a hard time with setting it up.

Are the calibration settings same for a Sigma lens for a particular camera model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every camera/lens combination will have different amounts of calibration. Comparing your settings to someone else’s will be of no use.